# Script is not generated for a stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework to create database scripts using the following code:

```
var dbScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```

I use the `MapToStoredProcedure()` method in my entity mapping class. This code generated a CREATE TABLE sql script only and does not generate a SQL script for the stored procedure.

How can I generate a SQL script for the stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript() is an old code path as database creation now uses the Migrations pipeline to create schema. For this reason, CreateDatabaseScript doesn't know how to process stored procedures.
Use this code :

```
var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true,
    ContextType = typeof(MyContext),
    MigrationsAssembly = typeof(MyContext).Assembly
};

var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
string script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null);

Console.WriteLine(script);
```